# Verificar se string inicia com numero

Tags: c#, regex

Preciso verificar se uma string começa com numeros. Quero fazer isso utilizando Regex em c#

```
public static class StringExtensao
{
    public static bool ComecaComNumero(this string str)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            return false;
        return char.IsNumber(Convert.ToChar( str.Substring(0,1)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A expressão para isso é bem simples:

```
"^\d"
```

Em uma função fica algo assim:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    bool ComecaComNumero(String s)
    {
        Regex r = new Regex(@"^\d");
        return r.Match(s).Success;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Algo assim?

```
public static bool IsNumber(string str)
{
    return new Regex(@"^[0-9]+").IsMatch(str);
}
```

[Fiz um Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6XzJN3).